# UIActivityViewController text is blown up in menu

Tags: ios, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using native UIActivityViewController, but for some reason the text is blown up. I couldn't find any property controller this. Any help is appreciated. Xcode version Version 7.1.1 (7B1005), iOS: 8.0+  Screenshots:

[image]

Comment: Are you customising your labels with UIAppearance?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez You got it mate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EmilioPelaez. I was customizing the `UIAlertController` font from which I invoke `UIActivityViewController`. Had to override `UIActivityViewController` font appearance:

```
UILabel * appearanceLabel = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:UIActivityViewController.class, nil];
[appearanceLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Regular" size:12.0f]];
```